# Div not re-positioning footer on dynamic table load

Tags: knockout.js, html-table

I am attempting to have a fixed header and footer around a div that is scrollable.

The footer does not re-position when the data is loaded to the table rows if I set the table Div to absolute (I get scroll bars though).  If I let it render default then the footer moves correctly to the bottom of the page but the table's div just expands to whatever size it needs and I have to use browser scroll.

```
<header/>
<div id="ListDiv">
    <table id="adapter-table" class="grid">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Manufacturer</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: Adapters">
            <tr>
                <td data-bind="text: Manufacturer"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: Name"></td>
                <td><a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.selectItem">Edit</a></td>
                <td><a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.deleteItem">Delete</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<footer/>
```

How do I get the table to scroll?  I don't care if the `thead` scrolls off the screen, it isn't complicated to figure out and the editing form underneath in the foot sorts of makes it unneeded.

I am trying this as my css:

```
body {
    height:100%;
}

header, footer {
    background: #ccc;
    height:20%;
}

#ListDiv{
    height: 60%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-y:auto;
}

.grid {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-spacing: 0;
    width: 95%;
}
```

I have set this up on http://jsfiddle.net/gregmason/UChLF/10/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed the height of the body to a fixed height, e.g.

```
body {
    height:400px;
}
```

This way, the rest of relative div's are calculated as relative of the parent element (body).

Comment: That does get it to allow scrolling again, thanks for that, but is there a way to allow it to auto size for different screen sizes?

Comment: perhaps calculate the height of the available space with javascript and set the height of the body on document load?

Comment: Ick... too much JS already for using knockout.  I prefer something that resizes as necessary.

Comment: Thanks to your comment I did figure out the problem, I am **not** a UI guy normally so this is fairly new to me.
`body {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}`
This ended up fixing it for me... relocated everything to the body and it all calculated out nicely. [JSFiddle Fixed](http://jsfiddle.net/gregmason/UChLF/11/)

Comment: You're welcome. And cool you figured it out. Fixing the header of your table is something you can do with the position: fixed CSS property.